# How to turn of semicolon error in a Eslint.js file and typescrip

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I want to use semicolons in my typescript files, but eslint is giving me an error Extra semicolon.eslint@typescript-eslint/semi now I went to the docs and it tells me to put this in my eslint file

```
"rules": {
    // Note: you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
    "semi": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/semi": "warn"
  }
```

The problem is that my eslint file is a .js file not a .json file so I can't put "@typescript-eslint/semi": "warn" because it gives me an error

Edit: this is the eslit.js file

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'standard-with-typescript'
  ],
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: ['./tsconfig.json']
  },
  plugins: ['react'],
  rules: {
    semi: 'off'
  }
};
```

Comment: show ur eslint.js then

Comment: @Dimava i just edited the question you can see it now

Comment: Just insert it after the semi you have there, I donlt get the problem

Comment: Also I don't recommend turning it off, better make VSCode `eslint autofix on save`

Comment: omg im so stupid i was adding '@typescript-eslint/semi' with out quotes as another property , and im using prettierr so it adds then on save

Comment: Here's your answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it into rules, the exaclty same way
DO NOT FORGET THE QUOTES

```
  plugins: ['react'],
  rules: {
    semi: 'off',
    "@typescript-eslint/semi": "warn" // < just add it
  }
};
```

Comment: my problem was this, i was forgeting the quotes

Comment: I you use rules alot, I recomment checking https://github.com/Shinigami92/eslint-define-config (tho you probably don't)